# how to do a "Move type to another file to match its name" accross a complete solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

does anyone know of a way to split all classes in one solution into multiple files?

The point here is that I've inherited a project in which a few hundred files contain a thousand or so classes...
I'd like to be able to get to a 1 file per class approach..

Using resharper I can easily do this manually, but I'm guessing there must be a better way?

Kind regards

Frederik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try one of the [ReSharper 5.0 nightly builds](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds) which allow you to do it across your whole solution. You can revert to ReSharper 4.5 (or whatever version you are using) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

GraemeF's answer is correct, but when you do that refactoring chances are you'll lose all source-control history for the existing classes.  This might not be a problem for you (especially if the system you've inherited wasn't source-controlled!) but I've often found that line-annotated views of a class are very helpful for determining the intent behind a particular line.

ReSharper has the Ctrl-T shortcut to jump to a type name, and holding down Ctrl makes types clickable; that might be another way to solve your problem.

Comment: I find the loss of source control information to be prohibitive, but I'm not sure at what level R# can hook into this stuff.  Having said that, Visual Studio + P4 does not even integrate files properly if you drag and drop using the solution explorer!  (e.g. drag a folder into a nested subfolder -- some of the files will get integrated, others won't).  If the 'normal' tools can't do it properly, I don't hold out much hope for other plugins :(